# Compute the mean of the float values in a certain column in a large MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I need to compute the mean of all the values in a particular column. I got this SQL statement which works:

```
SELECT SUM(`unitCost`)/COUNT(*) 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `itemID_FK`=%d
```

I'm looking for inputs on how to make this more efficient. This query can potentially lead to a large number of records having to be read.

I was wondering if it would be more efficient to maintain the mean value per `itemID_FK` in a separate table and keep updating the mean value as and when records are added to the `items` table?

I read somewhere that it is against the principles of database design to have a column that can be computed or derived from other columns or tables in the database.

EDIT:

**Columns:**

```
instanceID    int(10) UN PK AI
userID_FK     int(11) UN
itemID_FK     int(11) UN
dateAdded     date
datePurchased date
listID_FK     int(11) UN
unitCost      decimal(11,2) UN zerofill
quantity      decimal(11,2) UN zerofill
unitID_FK     int(10) UN
```

Comment: Is `itemID_FK` an `index` in your table? By the way, the `AVG` function should return what you want too.

Comment: @Bondye If I use GROUP BY I'm getting more than one record in the result set. Without GROUP BY `AVG` seems to work as expected.

Comment: @Bondye My bad, I've added more info; please see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very basic query, and it's unlikely that you'll find any way to make it actually run faster. There's an `avg()` function you could use, although it probably wouldn't be any faster.

As far as keeping averages in another table: it *is* against the generally held best practices of database design, but that doesn't mean you can't do it. People make compromises to improve performance; tradeoffs like that are the stock and trade of software developers. Doing this would make the query for averages faster, at the expense of program clarity and a little performance everywhere you do inserts, deletes, and updates on the master table.

Comment: It may be possible to do the updates/inserts with stored procedures, so clarity within programs might not get that bad.